# LED indicator is on but it only works to alert charging is incomplete (red) or complete (blue), it doesn't flash notifications

Tags: 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, notification-led

I have Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge on Android 8.0 Oreo ([additional software information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCJim.png)). Until yesterday, application notifications were flashing on the LED indicator, but from yesterday to today it stopped happening, even though nothing updated on the device.

It warns that it is charging with the red LED, and it warns when it has finished charging with the blue LED, but it does not flash to notify that there are new notifications as it used to do.

I checked if LED it's enabled, and yes it is.
I already checked if the applications are activated, yes they are.
I checked if it's in DO NOT DISTURB mode, and it's not.
I haven't changed any settings from yesterday to today, however, this is happening.

What can I check to try to find the problem?

Comment: Does it happen with a particular app or all of them? Does the issue persist if you restart the phone?

Comment: Hello @ReddyLutonadio , the answer is yes to both questions.

Comment: Hi @Robert Yes, I had already taken the test before asking the question but I repeated the test after the previous comment by Reddy Lutonadio, but the case persists unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that the LED functions properly. Go to your phone dial, and type in `*#0*#`.

This will bring up a test screen. press the 'led' option on the screen, and check the LED. Tap the screen to make the led change colours, if all colours are displayed, then the LED is functioning.

Comment: Hi, indicated test carried out successfully, LED working in its entirety, the case does not seem to be related to the non-functioning of the LED, including as stated in the question, it is working for options such as charging (red LED) and full charging (blue LED).

Comment: ok, was just checking. i am messing around with my closest phone to 8.0 oreo (my S5 lol - 6.0) to try to find something that might fix your problem.